# Wrap quotes around html in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have html that looks like this:

```
var content =  <p>Hello World</p> ;
```

I want to turn it into something like this:

```
var new_content =  "<p>Hello World</p>" ;
```

How would I go about doing this? I am new to Javascript and did some searching but could not find an answer.

Comment: The syntax is invalid.

Comment: Your html fragment in your first example is javascript?

Comment: Why do you have HTML that looks like that? Where does it come from? (Is it JSX, for example?)

Comment: The answer depends on where you got the HTML from.

Answer (score 0):

```
var new_content =  '"' + content + '"';
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this function to wrap in double quotes to the string representation of your HTML.

```
function wrapWithQuote(text) {
    return '"' + text + '"';
}
```